# Pandas - Invalid Key Issue

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure I understand this, PRICE clearly is a key in the DataFrame?  Samething with PURCHASEDATE, although I can retrieve the first two columns by key.

[image]

Update:

Thanks for the comments, it seems there was a space before the word PRICE in the CSV.  I would have thought this would be ignored?  Does PANDAS not ignore leading white space when parsing CSVs?  I would have hoped so for at least column names?

Comment: Probably whitespace in the csv. Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` and then `df['PRICE']`

Comment: It might happen that the column names contain spaces. What about doing that first: `df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]`.

Comment: I think that's it, would it not just ignore the white space in the columns?  I would hope it would in the values and the columns?

Comment: Blankspace? Try `'PRICE' in df.columns` and `df.info()`